# Mirth connect: unable to start channel

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I'm trying to start a Mirth channel with a simple TCP Listener source but I'm getting the following error:

```
[2018-07-31 11:38:44,185]  ERROR (com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ErrorTaskHandler:25): com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.StartException: Failed to start channel Test-Channel (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.start(Channel.java:724)

    at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.DonkeyEngineController$ChannelStatusTask.execute(DonkeyEngineController.java:1928)

    at com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ChannelTask.call(ChannelTask.java:67)

    at com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ChannelTask.call(ChannelTask.java:16)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.ConnectorTaskException: Failed to create server socket (TCP Listener "Source" on channel xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpReceiver.onStart(TcpReceiver.java:179)

    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.start(SourceConnector.java:104)

    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.start(Channel.java:700)

    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)

    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)

    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)

    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.StateAwareServerSocket.<init>(StateAwareServerSocket.java:36)

    at com.mirth.connect.plugins.ssl.server.SecureTcpConfiguration.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)

    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpReceiver.createServerSocket(TcpReceiver.java:895)

    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpReceiver.onStart(TcpReceiver.java:177)

    ... 9 more
```

It looks like a port is already in use. I've tried changing the source's "Local port" but I keep getting this error.

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It clearly states that "Address already in use". What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 3):

Look for some other application listening on this same port. The easy way to test for this, in this instance, would be to change your port number in your TCP Listener to something else. For testing, I would choose something above 32000, and deploy the channel again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mirthconnect channel is working after I have changed the port number.